# Can I use a specific dictionary key as a DataTextField if that dictionary is a property of my datasource?

Tags: c#, dictionary, telerik, rad-controls, datatextfield

Rough class schema:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid ID;
    public Dictionary<String, object> Attributes;
}
```

Attributes has the following keys: `listname (string), membercount(integer), type (boolean)`.

I have a Telerik RadComboBox which is databound through code-behind to a List and has an ItemTemplate:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="CboLists" DataValueField="Id">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Attributes['listname']") %></b> (<%# ViewHelper.GetBooleanValue("list", "type",(bool)((Entity)Container.DataItem).Attributes["type"]) %>)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Attributes['membercount']") %> Leden
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I want to show the value of the Attribute with key `listname` in the combobox as the DataTextField, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I've checked on here and everything I can find on using dictionaries in a combobox involves using a dictionary as the datasource. I would think it's possible, because it works in the ItemTemplate, and I can get it to work in a RadGrid on the DataField property using `Attributes[listname]`, but when I try that construct, it doesn't work.

How can i get this to work?

Comment: When you say "I try that construct, it doesn't work", how does it not work? Does it throw any errors or just display blank/wrong data?

Comment: it says that it cannot find Attributes[listname] on that Entity or something along those lines. But I've checked the object during debugging, and it's there. I just need to figure out how to access it. I've tried it using single quotes, escaped double quotes and no quotes. all of them fail. i've tried using Eval(Attributes[listname]) and that tries to get a class called attributes.